# How do I assign variable value for name in named list?

Tags: r, list

I want to assign char value from variable to use name in named list.

```
n <- "EDF04"
l1 <- list(n = c(1,2,3))
Result:
$c
[1] 1 2 3

Expected Result:
$EDF04
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: `names(l1) <- n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for `names<-` ?

```r
n  <- "EDF04"
l1 <- list(n = c(1,2,3))
names(l1) <- n
l1
#> $EDF04
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

or `setNames`?

```
setNames(list(c(1,2,3)), n)
#> $EDF04
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

Or are you wanting to do something fancier?

```r
mylist <- function(...) {
  mc <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  par_names <- names(mc)
  li_names <- sapply(par_names, function(i){
    if(nzchar(i)) {
      a_name <- if(exists(i, envir = parent.frame()))
        get(i, envir = parent.frame()) else i
        if(length(a_name) == 1 & class(a_name) == "character") return(a_name)
    } else return("")
  })
  setNames(list(...), li_names)
}

mylist(n = 1, z = 4, c(5, 6, 7)) 
#> $EDF04
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $z
#> [1] 4
#>
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 5 6 7
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>